# How do I repass routerLink and queryParams everytime when I clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, iframe

Which will pass this `routerLink` and `queryParams` to an `iframe` in another component and that iframe will load the home page of another website. The user can go further inside that iframe by clicking buttons or links inside that home page.

Is there a way that when the user clicks this `<a>` link again and iframe reload to the home page?

Currently, this  link is not clickable if the user is already in this iframe, whether on the iframe home page or further subpage inside the iframe home page.

```html
<li data-toggle="collapse" class="nav-link1 pda">
  <a
    class="nav-link"
    routerLink="/financial-tool"
    [queryParams]="application_data"
    [routerLinkActive]="['active']"
  >
    <span class="pcoded-micon"><i class="fas fa-landmark"></i></span>
    <span class="pcoded-mtext font-12">Applications</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

Basically, I want to refresh the iframe by clicking this  link. I appreciate it if someone can give me some hints, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you can do is use a **BUTTON** instead of 
You can have `refreshIFrame()` function in `<script>` tag.
When user clicks on the refresh button, this function is called and iframe is reloaded.

You can do something of this kind

```
<iframe id=iframe-click src=""></iframe>  

<script>
    document.getElementById("iframe-click").src = "<link>";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but seems like it won't work for me, I am using Angular.